# Visual studio 2013 with windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am designing an calculator interface with visual studio 2013.I need to enclose "{" and "}" braces as two buttons in calculator.But when "{" button include as the button content,there is an error saying "mark up extension does not properly called".How can I enter the "{" brace just as a sign in the content field.
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what is your problem, could you include the failing code and markup? And please specify in your tags also the language used and the target platform (WPF, ASP.NET, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

In XAML you can escape the curly brace by adding extra opening and closing curly brace like this:

```
<Button Content="{}{This is a text with curly braces}" />
```

Or you can use the extended version without any escaping:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        {This is a text with curly braces}
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```